# Query from sys.sysusers returns only part of records

Tags: sql-server

Why so different results?

I do not receive the part of records users created database roles:

SQL 2016

```
User sa:
SELECT * FROM sys.sysusers;
---
42 records

Domain User:
SELECT * FROM sys.sysusers;
---
22 records
```

May be need to correct permissions? where?

Comment: First this view is obsolete. Second different priviliges - so you don't see all data

Comment: What permissions I need to see full recordset?